# Can't write Scandinavian letters in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, character-encoding, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to make a simple plot in MATLAB r2014a, on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine, some of the labels contains some of the Scandinavian letters æ(Æ), ø(Ø) and å(Å).

But when i'm trying to use whose letters in a label I just get some trash on the plot. 
I've checked the encoding MATLAB is using with.

```
slCharacterEncoding()
```

It returns UTF-8 with should allow whose letters, i've also tried to change it to windows-1252 which works on windows with the letters.

I know that i can use the 'interpret' 'latex' but i'm looking for a permanent solution.

EDIT:
After some time i figured that the letters are available, if i write in the terminal

```
char(230)
```

I get a 'æ' i also fond the other letters with the numbers:
æ = 230, ø = 248, å = 229, Æ = 199, Ø = 216, Å = 198
Is it possible to remap them ?

Comment: To my experience, 'interpret' 'latex' is the only permanent solution. Why isn't this a solution for you?

Comment: Because it changes the font of the label, and since i'm using the plots in a report which i'm writing with other students I'd like the labels to look alike each other.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957988/how-to-use-non-ascii-characters-in-matlab-figures-for-use-in-latex-doc)?

Comment: Yea, I've tried the interpret solution, and i works, but it gives me a weird font

Comment: Hi @Niva, so strange! I am using MATLAB2013a and I have no problems with Norwegian words, may be because I am running it on windows?
Perhaps you can send your codes to your mates and they can run the graphs for you!

Comment: Yea, it works on Windows and Mac, but me and two of my friends, also with Ubuntu, are having the problem.
I could of course send it to my friends but it takes a lot of time, specially now when we are correcting the report.